# Redhat | ftp configuration

Tags: ftp, redhat

I'm looking for a way to configure the ftp setting in my Redhat EL 5.4 (64bit) server in order to transfer some files from my client machine. I have search all over the net but couldn't find any good resources. I'm really new to Redhat and requesting a proper guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# yum install vsftpd
# nano /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
  chroot_local_user=YES
# chkconfig vsftpd on
# service vsftpd start
# nano /etc/sysconfig/iptables
   -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
# service iptables restart
```

Comment: Hi, where do I add the chroot_local_ser=YES in the vsftpd.conf. I didn't see this line on that file...

Comment: If you want to chroot your users (jail them to their homedir) you just add "chroot_local_user=YES" somewhere in the vsftpd.conf file.

Comment: Plus I'm getting an error 530 Permission denied

Comment: Set: anonymous_enable=NO in vsftpd.conf

Comment: Did it but not working, works only for normal users

Comment: Could you tell me exactly what you want to do? "Works only for normal users" What kind of users does it not work for?

Comment: I'm trying to transfer some files from my client machine to the server (RH EL 5.4)...normal users mean the users that I have created apart from the root/administrator.. The problem is that the root user can't connect through ftp.. throws the error 530 Permission denied.

Comment: very unsecure and the password for root will be passed over the LAN in cleartext, not recommended at all but try:

userlist-enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO

You really should think about doing this via ssh/scp instead, but I'm helping you on the ftp part as it was what the question was about.

Comment: Can u please explain me briefly how to do so (secure ftp).. I managed to setup fuse and ssh, but I don't know how to transfer files. client is Windows XP..

Comment: Download "winscp" (windows app) (free/open source) and connect to your box, works almost like a ftp-client.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly an answer, but I would recommend using SFTP instead of FTP. It's easier to setup given the fact that every box comes with the OpenSSH server and client. It's also more secure and [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) is nice bonus, although I don't know if RHEL has support for it.

Comment: You could also use scp for simple file transfers.